# Some help for a beginner

Tags: python

I have to make a list out of some elements in a dictionary in Python 3:

```py
fruits = {
    'apple' : {'price' : '13', weight : '15'},
    'orange' : {'price' : '8', weight : '11'}
}
```

How can I make a list that only  shows me the price of all fruits?

Comment: `[ x [ 'price' ] for _, x in fruits.items() ]` should work in Python3. (It's `iteritems()` in Python2)

Comment: Why would you put the numbers as string?

Answer (score 2):

you may use `operator.itemgetter` as the following

```
from operator import itemgetter

fruits = {'apple' : {'price' : '13', 'weight' : '15'}, 'orange' : {'price' : '8', 'weight' : '11'}}

priceList = list(map(itemgetter('price'), fruits.values()))

print(priceList)
```

**output:**

```
['13', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you that:

```
fruits = {'apple' : {'price' : '13', 'weight' : '15'}, 'orange' : {'price' : '8', 
         'weight' : '11'}}
output = {k:v['price'] for k,v in fruits.items()}
print(output)
```

which results in:

```
{'apple': '13', 'orange': '8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the list of fruit prices:

```py
fruits = {
    "apple": {"price": "13", "weight": "15"},
    "orange": {"price": "8", "weight": "11"},
}

# using list comprehension
fruits_prices = [fruit_info.get("price") for fruit_info in fruits.values()]

# using loop
fruit_prices = []
for fruit_info in fruits.values():
    fruit_prices.append(fruit_info.get("price"))

print(fruit_prices)
```

This gives you a list of fruit prices:

```py
['13', '8']
```